# FileSaver.js removing BOM

Tags: byte-order-mark, filesaver.js

I am using FileSaver.js and trying to can't get rid of BOM ï»¿ in saved file. I tried disableAutoBOM set to true but it didn't help. Also trying to replace with "" , see below, nothing works

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
            filename = "autoconf.clish".replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", "");
            saveAs(blob, filename, true);
```

Comment: updated filesaver and all is fine